# How to create a square button (90 degree angles) Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-button, material-components-android

So while fiddling around in Android Studio I came with the question: 'How do you make the corners of the button square?. Looking around the internet and stack overflow I got many answers, but I wondered if there was a much simpler way... and then poof! Under Common attributes in XML design, I saw background, curious I put in `'@android:color/white'` inside, and then the rounded square button became a 90-degree square button.

This was a nice surprise. Since I didn't see anyone talk about doing this I decided to post here. Hope it was helpful and a quick hack to having 90-degree corners on your buttons!

[image]

> Code difference Back(with background) and home(no background)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="Back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:text="Home"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.007" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To achieve a square button just use the attribute **`app:cornerRadius="0dp"`**:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        app:cornerRadius="0dp"/>
```

Just note that if you are using a Material Components Theme the `Button` is replaced at runtime by a `MaterialButton`.

[image]

Note about the `android:background="@color/white"`.
Using the `android:background` attribute the `MaterialButton` **doesn't use** its own `MaterialShapeDrawable` for the background. This means that features like shape appearance, stroke and rounded corners are ignored.
It is the reason because you are obtaining a square button.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create background xml file for your button

and you can give any shape

Answer (score 1):

To create a square button you can create a drawable resource file and you make the root element shape afterwards you can give the shape a color  or a stroke  and then for it to be a square you have to pass the same height and the same width e.g width 100dp and height 100dp. 
 Below is an example of how you can get a drawable that is a square:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp"/>
</shape>
```